# How to use client to post the realm role in Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, roles, keycloak-rest-api

I have created a client in keycloak and configure it access type to "confidential".

I can use REST API `protocol/openid-connect/token` with clientId and client secret to get the access token for this this client.

In my design, there is a use case that I need to use the client access token to post a role in its Realm (the role needs to belong to realm, not this client). Then I can see the post request is denied. I have configured the scope of this client to full scope but it doesn't help.

Any idea whether this is possible? If yes, what configs I need for this client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

**(OLD Keycloak UI)**

1. To go your Realm > Clients and select your client;
2. Switch `Service Accounts Enabled` to `ON`, and click `[SAVE]`;
3. Switch to `Service Accounts Roles` tab;
4. From the `Client Roles` dropdown menu select the `realm-management` client
5. Select `realm-admin`, and click `Add Selected` and tried it out.

[image]

**(New Keycloak UI)**

1. Select your Realm then go to `Clients` and select your client;
2. In Authentication flow select `Service accounts roles` and click `[SAVE]`;
3. Switch to `Service Accounts Roles` tab;
4. Click on `Assign Role`
5. On the `Search by role name` search for the role name 'realm-admin', then select it and click on `Assign`

[image]

Comment: oh wow, thanks a 1000 times. I was searching for this for hours.